# Using NLTK to capture proper nouns with lower case prepositions

Tags: python, nltk

I've been getting started with NLTK to find proper nouns. However, I'm having difficulty getting proper nouns (Names of People and Organizations) that have lower case prepositions within them.

For instance,

```
The David Eccles School of Business at the University of Utah
```

becomes (with my nltk POS tagger):

```
David Eccles School, Business, University
```

Another example:

```
The United Nations Economic and Social Council's Economic Commission for Africa
```

Becomes

```
United Nations Economic, Social Council, Economic Commission, Africa
```

Any suggestions?

Some that I'm considering (capitalizing all prepositions and the's)

```
    tokens2 = nltk.word_tokenize(x)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens2)
    res = nltk.ne_chunk(tags)
    tree = []
    for subtree in res.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'PERSON'):
        subtree_l=[]
        for leaf in subtree.leaves():
            subtree_l.append(leaf[0])
        sub = ' '.join(subtree_l)
        tree.append(sub)

    for subtree in res.subtrees(filter=lambda t: t.node == 'ORGANIZATION'):
        subtree_l=[]
        for leaf in subtree.leaves():
            subtree_l.append(leaf[0])
        sub = ' '.join(subtree_l)
        tree.append(sub)
    x= ', '.join(tree)
    count = count+1
    print x
```