# NLTK Relation Extraction - how to grab organization names with prepositions and conjunctions within them?

Tags: python, nltk

How do I capture ORGS or PERSONS with prepositions in them with NLTK?

Let's say my `text` is the following:

> 'The following information was released by Rutgers University:    Center for Urban Entrepreneurship and Economic Development (CUEED) travelled to  Shanghai, China in November to help lead "The Global S'

I'd ideally like to output:

```
Center for Urban Entrepreneurship and Economic Development
```

Right now I get:

```
Center/NNP
  for/IN
  (PERSON Urban/NNP Entrepreneurship/NNP)
  and/CC
  (ORGANIZATION Economic/NNP Development/NNP)
```

I've been trying to mess around with turning the named entity output into a string and using regex to capture word tags, but failing (my code below). WOuld greatly appreciate your help.

```
for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
    tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
    namedEnt = nltk.ne_chunk(tagged, binary=False)
    #print str(namedEnt), '|', str(namedEnt).index('was/VBD')
        #entities = re.findall(r'(ORGANIZATION|PERSON)\s(.*?)/',str(namedEnt))
    print re.findall(r'\/IN.*', str(namedEnt))
```

Comment: You seem to have been [struggling with this for a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494116/using-nltk-to-capture-proper-nouns-with-lower-case-prepositions). This is very difficult to solve in the general case (as many natural language parsing problems are), partly because there are so many different structures of organisation name.

Comment: @jonrsharpe do you have any suggestions for alternative things to dO? my general goal is to find organizational collaborations linked in text, but I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to do this.

Comment: You're having a hard time *because it's hard*. This is really not an easy task to approach.

Comment: This isn't a simple problem, maybe what you could do is detect the abbreviation CUEED and use that to look for the full form somewhere nearby and make a decision based on that. Not simple or ideal,  but it's something. Or you could give it a large set including such labelled examples and make it find patterns around such organizations using different features. It's a big research problem!